# Angular4.4.3 html in template does not throw errors

Tags: html, angular

Certain views of my app don't load but when i inspect the view is there but not rendered. I did research on how HTML works and it turns out if you anyone leaves out a tag unclosed, HTML looks for the last tag and loads that. I fixed all those issues in my code however the problem still persists on some views yet I have all tags closed. What could be the problem? Is there any tool or anything i could add to detect such issues?

In initiate-bill.component.html

```
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <h3 class="text-align">Iniatiate bill payments</h3>
          </div>
        </div> -->
        <!-- row ends here for title -->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header card-header-text" data-background-color="cyan">
                        <h3 class="card-title">Initiate bill payment</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-content">

                        <form [formGroup]="IniateBillGroup">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                    <div class="input-group">
    <span
            class="input-group-addon">
<i class="material-icons">phone</i></span>
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter customer's number" class="form-control"

                                        >
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-group">
    <span
            class="input-group-addon">
<i class="material-icons">monetization_on</i></span>
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter amount" class="form-control"

                                        >
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="input-group">
      <span
              class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="material-icons">lock_open</i></span>
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter pin " class="form-control"

                                        >
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </div> <!--row stops here-->

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-3"></div>
                                <!-- Add the extra clearfix for only the required viewport -->
                                <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-3">


                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-primary">SEND<i
                                            class="material-icons">payment</i>

                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </form>


                    </div>
                </div><!--card ends here-->


            </div><!--col ends here-->
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

in initiate-bill.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup,FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-initiate-bill',
  templateUrl: './initiate-bill.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./initiate-bill.component.scss']
})
export class InitiateBillComponent implements OnInit {
IniateBillGroup: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.IniateBillGroup = this.fb.group({
      customerNumber: '',
      amount: '',
      pin: ''
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: It works for me. https://plnkr.co/edit/0iUwDj7MaHw2rHzgOKL8?p=preview

Comment: is there any runtime error or console error in a browser?

Comment: no there isn't code runs well except that the views don't load when the  app initializes. But when I hard type the url in the browser localhost://4200/history it does load